# Set the same background in all windows forms with a single setting

Tags: c#, winforms

i have 40 windows forms in a C# Project. i have to set the same background in all forms. is any option or settings to do that in a single settings?

Comment: By using App.config and binding background color to the config?

Comment: You could create your form class, set the background color and inherit all your form from this form.

Answer (score 3):

You can create base form and set the background for it and other form inherit from the base form.

```
class baseForm: Form {
    void base() {
        this.BackColor = //set here
    }
}

class YourForm : baseForm {

}
```

Comment: +1 for the `BaseForm`. While the application grows you'll probably want to have more and more shared stuff and using a `BaseForm` is good way to accomplish this

Comment: @Leron yes i agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative, if you cannot use inheritence then you can refactor the code that applies the styling into a single place and then you only need to apply one line to every form. In fact with a little syntactic sugar (aka an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)) you can make it look it was always part of your class anyway

i.e.

```
//Example form with an inheritor that blocks us from using inheritence to apply style
public class MainForm : 3rdPartyLibrary.WizardForm 
{
  public MainForm()
  {
    ApplyStyle();
  }
}

//Normal form 
public class MyDialog : Form
{
  public MyDialog()
  {
    ApplyStyle();
  }
}

public static class WinFormExtension
{
  public static void ApplyStyle(this Form form)
  {
    form.BackColor = Colors.NavyBlue;
    //etc
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Work with Inheritance.

Create a Basic form, set the background property and inherit with all forms to the Basicform.

But im not sure, if the Visual Studio Gui-Desginer can handle Inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance is the right way to go about this, but sometimes it's fun to do things the *wrong* way too (though not in production of course):

```
var type = typeof (Color).Assembly.GetType("System.Drawing.KnownColorTable");
var field = type.GetField("colorTable",
                          BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
var colorTable = (int[]) field.GetValue(null);
colorTable[(int) KnownColor.Control] = Color.Blue.ToArgb();
colorTable[(int) KnownColor.ControlText] = Color.Red.ToArgb();
new Form {Controls = {new Button {Text = "Success!"}}}.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

We solved this issue by adding the color code in your base form load function, which is inherited to child forms without issues.

```
        private void BaseForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            // put your color code here
    }
```