# How to set Background image in master page using windows form application C#?

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I set a background image in the master form then I call in the child form it's not working

I set the background image in the properties of the master form. if I put any other tool like buttons panel it working on the child form

Master Form

```
public partial class MasterForm: Form
{
    public MasterForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Child Form

here I call like this

```
public partial class item: MasterForm
{
}
```

Comment: " then I call in the child form it's not working" what exactly? does the childform not show up? or does the setting of the background image not work in the child form?

Comment: @Mong Zhu I'm using WinForms not a web application

Comment: @Mong Zhu child form does not show the background image

Comment: @Mong zhu I set the background image in the properties of the Master Form so I say like that.

Comment: @ Mong Zhu, my problem is I want to set a single background image in all the windows forms

Comment: please post the code from the designer, that shows the setting of the background image. is the class `item` a simple class or is it a Windows Form? Also where is the call of the Child Form?

Comment: @Mohg zhu wait I will put a screenshot soon you will understand what my problem is

Comment: I need the code that calls and shows the child form. Because when I try it then my child form has the same background image! But it will also have the same layout of control elements!

Comment: @Mohg Zhu I refer code from here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deveshomar/master-page-in-C-Sharp-window-forms/

Comment: You probably should tag MDI, right?

Comment: mate, a link to where you got the code from is cool, but probably the person who wrote the code on this link did not have your problem. So we need to see **your** code, because you have the problem. Otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First create BaseMasterForm.cs and inherit Form. Write your code if you want added something in constructor.
2. Second create Child Form.cs and inherit BaseMasterForm. You can override Show Background. If you want to show Background you need to set true.

BaseMasterForm .cs

```
public class BaseMasterForm : Form
{
    // You can override this Show Background. If you want or not to show background.
    public virtual bool ShowBackground { get { return true; } }

    public BaseMasterForm()
    {
        this.Load += (s, e) =>
        {
            // your image
            this.BackgroundImage = (ShowBackground) ? Properties.Resources.LeeQc : null;
            // you can custom
            this.BackgroundImageLayout = (ShowBackground) ? ImageLayout.Stretch : ImageLayout.None;
        };
    }
}
```

ChildForm.cs

```
public partial class ChildForm : BaseMasterForm
{
    // set true or false. to show MasterForm background.
    public override bool ShowBackground { get { return true; } }

    public ChildForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thank Guys for the guidance

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not working because every page has it's own properties. You have to set the image in the MasterForm.

```
public partial class MasterForm: Form
{
    public MasterForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.Image;
    }
}
```

See here: [Set the same background in all windows forms with a single setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21252416/set-the-same-background-in-all-windows-forms-with-a-single-setting)